# Python Why table[0][:] == table[:][0]

Tags: python, list

Why does `tab2D[:][0]` and `tab2D[0][:]` gives this same result?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    table2D = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]

    print(table2D[:][0]) #[1,2,3]
    print(table2D[0][:]) #[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both have the same *values*, but they are two different lists.

`table2D[:]` creates a copy of `table2D` and `[0]` takes the first index of that copy, so

```
table2D[:][0]
```

is index 0 in a copy of `table2D`.

`table2D[0]` takes the first index of `table2D` and `[:]` creates a copy of that list, so

```
table2D[0][:]
```

is a copy of index 0 in `table2D`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not **exactly** same.
They looks like having same values.
But they have different references.

```py
table2D = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

a = table2D[0][:]
b = table2D[:][0]

a[0] = 0
print(table2D[0])  # [1, 2, 3]
b[0] = 0
print(table2D[0])  # [0, 2, 3]
```